# Opencart3 - как программно получить information_id?

Tags: opencart

Есть шаблон в opencart3, и создано несколько информационных страниц.
Появилась необходимость подключать различные css стили в зависимости от страницы.

Как понимаю это проще всего сделать в twig файле, где в шаблоне собирается header оператором if...
Для этого в контроллере надо получить ИД страницы, и передать его в twig файл...

Как получить id страницы?
P.S.
В перспективе интересно было бы и в id раздела эту же функциональность добавить...

Answer (score 1):

Открываем контроллер `header`.

Ищем такие строки (у меня стандартный шаблон):

```
$data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle();

$data['base'] = $server;
$data['description'] = $this->document->getDescription();
$data['keywords'] = $this->document->getKeywords();
$data['links'] = $this->document->getLinks();
$data['styles'] = $this->document->getStyles();
$data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts('header');
$data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code');
$data['direction'] = $this->language->get('direction');
```

Ниже этих строчек добавляем условие:

```
if( !empty($this->request->get['information_id']) ){ // Проверяем, находимся ли мы на информационной странице
    $data['pageid'] = $this->request->get['information_id']; // Получаем id страницы
}
```

Теперь в шаблоне `header.twig` вы можете работать с переменной `pageid`, которая содержит `id` страницы.